# Is there a way to disable Vulkan scissor test?

Tags: vulkan

If not does that mean it's always enabled? And any time I render to a different a different size I need to create another pipeline? Setting viewport dynamically is a standard feature in Vulkan 1.0, and scissor I don't even use so I'd like to disable it, if possible.

Comment: The scissor box has been part of dynamic state since day 1. There's no reason you can't just have your pipelines use it that way.

Comment: You pretty much always need scissor to make sure you don't write out of bounds...